# Argument labels '(contents0f:,fileTypeHint:)' do not match any available overloadsの解決方法

Tags: swift, xcode

最近swiftを始めたばかりの者です。本を見ながら楽器アプリを作っているのですが、下記エラーにはまってしまい先に進めません。
Argument labels '(contents0f:,fileTypeHint:)' do not match any available overloads

解決方法がわからないので教えていただけますと幸いです。
コードは以下の通りです。

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  MyMusic
//
//  Created by  on 2018/06/30.
//  Copyright © 2018年 Swift-Beginners. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

//シンバルの音源ファイルを指定
  let cymbalPath = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("cymbal.mp3")

  //シンバル用のプレイヤーインスタンスを作成
  var cymbalPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

  @IBAction func cymbal(_ sender: Any) {
    do{
    //シンバル用のプレイヤーに、音源ファイル名を指定
      cymbalPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contents0f: cymbalPath, fileTypeHint: nil)
    cymbalPlayer.play()
    } catch {
      print("シンバルで、エラーが発生しました！")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 間違いの内容が完全に同じではないですが、ほぼ同じということで重複と扱って良さそうですね> @nakano531 さん。リンク先の回答をよく呼んで見てください。＞hana さん。

Comment: リンク先の回答の方は綴りミスが原因だったようですが、私のコードにも綴りミスがあるのでしょうか？自分のコードを何度か確認しましたが見つかりません。もしあったら教えていただけますと幸いです。

Comment: `contentsOf` がcontentsオーfではなく、contentsゼロfになっていますね。シンタックスハイライティングで一目瞭然になっています。

Comment: contentsゼロfをcontentsオーfに変更して見たのですが、エラーが無くなりません。

Comment: @hana さん、こちらではその修正で表題のエラーは出なくなりました。コードを修正した後、クリーンビルドは試みられたでしょうか?